# EventBridge responseElements too large

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-event-bridge

EventBridge/CloudTrail pass the below json string to my lambda function when the results get too long.
Is there anyway to view the responseElements like [paginators](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) or [NextToken](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=ec2#EC2.Client.describe_addresses_attribute)?

```
"responseElements":{
    "omitted":true,
    "originalSize":175918,
    "reason":"responseElements too large"
}
```

I'm using the following EventBridge pattern

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["RunInstances"]
  }
}
```

Comment: You could perhaps use [lookup_events](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudtrail.html#CloudTrail.Client.lookup_events), passing the event ID, but I suspect that it will be truncated as well (so this is not an answer).

Comment: I'm assuming that this is output from a Lambda? If yes, I think a better solution might be to store that output somewhere (like S3) and return a reference to it.

Comment: This is the event sent to the lambda function by eventbridge not my lambdas output.

Comment: In the cloudtrail > event history searching by the event ID. Im seeing the same error :(

Comment: Re my second question, I was making an assumption based on the size of the `responseElements` payload. I should have looked at your second code snippet to see that it was from a `RunInstances` call. I'm not sure why the payload is so large (in my experience, it's normally 2-3k for that call), but I'm wondering if maybe `lookup_events` will still work for you, because it should include the resource ID. If you have the instance ID, you should be able to retrieve everything that you'd find in the CloudTrail event.

Comment: I like my clusters big ;) but no luck with `lookup_events` or the cloud trail UIs history page. Same message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of CloudTrail, so at this time it's not be possible to pass that information from CloudTrail if it exceeds 100KB.

Potential work-around that may be useful to others with this message is to create an EventBridge rule to track EC2 instance state changes. So instead of monitoring the api call runinstances look for instances changing into the state running triggering from that as this should have a smaller response.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-CloudWatch-Logs.html